# Always re-run puppet exec ressource on each provision

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have an exec resource in a puppet script that should be executed on each provision but it doesn't seem to be working. I might have a configuration problem or logical execution order problem but i'm not sure where it is.

```
exec { 'get-ec2-hosts-run':
  environment => "HOME=/home/${common_username}",
  command     => "php /home/${common_username}/get-ec2-hosts.php",
  refresh     => "php /home/${common_username}/get-ec2-hosts.php",
  require     => [
    Package["php7.1"],
    File_line['export aws access key'],
    File_line['export aws secret key'],
  ],
  user        => "${common_username}"
}
```

So i use that code to actually always run and even refresh on each provision the script called get-ec2-hosts.php which just describes instances and write a ~/.ssh/config file for me. A very needed file in our architecture actually.

If i run this file manually, it works fine and creates my config file but from any provision step it never seems to run although i do get a line in the puppet provisionning output saying it did it!

```
==> local_dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[php71-add-tools]/returns: executed successfully
==> local_dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[php71-add-repo]/returns: executed successfully
==> local_dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[php71-update-sources]/returns: executed successfully
==> local_dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[get-ec2-hosts-run]/returns: executed successfully
==> local_dev: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[get-ec2-hosts-copy]/returns: executed successfully
==> local_dev: Notice: Finished catalog run in 6.57 seconds
```

So i'm wondering what i am doing wrong here.

Goal:

1. Run get-ec2-hosts.php on every provision (vagrant provision, vagrant up --provision or vagrant reload --provision)

Condition:

1. Must run after php 7.1 is installed
2. Must run after aws credentials have been installed in the "common_username"
3. Must run as that user to create the file without problem

Can you help me understand this?

Comment: Set `logoutput => true` in the `exec` resource and see what is occurring when that resource is being applied.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately i have to postpone this as we are in a RC process. Once done i'll come back to this and try your suggestion